# SQL selecting date by month and year but select another month/year rows by column relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following example in my database:

| workshop_class_id | workshop_session_id | workshop_class_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 209 | 29 | 2021-06-20 |
| 210 | 29 | 2021-06-21 |
| 213 | 31 | 2021-06-30 |
| 211 | 30 | 2021-06-30 |
| 214 | 31 | 2021-07-01 |
| 212 | 30 | 2021-07-03 |
| 219 | 33 | 2021-07-12 |

I would like to select by month and year, for example June 2021, but if the rows have relation with `workshop_session_id` and even if the date it's not in June 2021, I would like to have these rows.

In the example, I have two rows in July related with dates in June, only the row with the `workshop_session_id` 33 will be excluded.

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your answers! The accepted answer is the one that fit the best my working environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way DB can use a possible index on `workshop_class_date`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE workshop_session_id IN (
   SELECT t1.workshop_session_id 
   FROM yourTable t1 
   WHERE t1.workshop_class_date BETWEEN date '2021-06-01' AND date `2021-06-30`) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery to find all session id in a particular month and then search those session id in whole table. If they exists in another month then they will also be listed.

Solution with Demo queries:

```
Create table myTable (workshop_class_id int, workshop_session_id int, workshop_class_date date);
    
    Insert into myTable values(209, 29, '2021-06-20');
    Insert into myTable values(210, 29, '2021-06-21');
    Insert into myTable values(213, 31, '2021-06-30');
    Insert into myTable values(211, 30, '2021-06-30');
    Insert into myTable values(214, 31, '2021-07-01');
    Insert into myTable values(212, 30, '2021-07-03');
    Insert into myTable values(219, 33, '2021-07-12');
    
    Select *
    from myTable tab
    join 
    (Select distinct workshop_Session_ID from myTable 
    where date_part('month',workshop_class_date) = 6 
    and date_part('year',workshop_class_date) = 2021
    ) sid on tab.workshop_Session_ID = sid.workshop_Session_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggets using exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    DATE_TRUNC('month', t1.workshop_class_date)::date  = '2021-06-01' OR
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
            WHERE t2.workshop_session_id = t1.workshop_session_id AND
                  t2.workshop_class_id <> t1.workshop_class_id AND
                  DATE_TRUNC('month', t2.workshop_class_date)::date  = '2021-06-01');
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic here says to retain and June or any record from any other month/year for which we can find a common workshop session ID with a June record.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use analytical function to count the number of occurrences and then filter by date or number of occurrences

```
with a as (
  select t.*, count(*) over(partition by workshop_session_id) as cnt
  from your_table t
)
select *
from a
where workshop_class_date between date '2021-06-01' and date '2021-06-30'
  or cnt > 1
```